# How to give "Only Child" a longer vertical line using nodes?

Tags: css

See pic - in this tree an 'Only Child' is not horizontally aligned with other children:

[image: not aligned]

I can see this is caused by CCS which  removes space from the top of single children, but removing that CSS shows the vertical line as being too short:

[image: line too short]

Anyone have a solution of how to make an only child horizontally aligned with other children?

Thanks

```css
.genealogy-body{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 50px;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.genealogy-tree{
  display: inline-block;
}
.genealogy-tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.genealogy-tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}
.genealogy-tree li::before, .genealogy-tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 50%;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; 
  height: 18px;
}
.genealogy-tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}
/*This removes left & right connectors from elements without any siblings*/
*.genealogy-tree li:only-child::after, .genealogy-tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}
/*This removes space from the top of single children BUT IT CAUSES MISALIGNMENT SO NEED TO EXTEND LINE SOMEHOW*/
.genealogy-tree li:only-child{ 
    padding-top: 0;
}
/*This removes left connector from first child and right connector from last child*/
.genealogy-tree li:first-child::before, .genealogy-tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*This adds back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.genealogy-tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.genealogy-tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*This adds downwards connectors from parents*/
.genealogy-tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}
.genealogy-tree li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Lora", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
        
<div class="body genealogy-body genealogy-scroll">
    <div class="genealogy-tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a>
        <div class="member-view-box">
        <div class="member-image">
        <img src="../images/trees/_tree_blank.jpg" alt="refresh your browser...">
        <div class="member-details">
        <span><strong>Top<br>Line</strong></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>        
            <a>
            <div class="member-view-box">
            <div class="member-image">
            <div class="member-details">
            <span><strong>PARENT<br>WITH<br>ONE CHILD</strong></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a>
                <div class="member-view-box">
                <div class="member-image">
                <div class="member-details">
                <span><strong>ONLY<br>CHILD</strong><br>* line short *</span>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a>
            <div class="member-view-box">
            <div class="member-image">
            <div class="member-details">
            <span><strong>PARENT<br>WITH<br>TWO CHILDS</strong></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a>
                <div class="member-view-box">
                <div class="member-image">
                <div class="member-details">
                <span><strong>Child 1<br>of 2</strong></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a>
                <div class="member-view-box">
                <div class="member-image">
                <div class="member-details">
                <span><strong>Child 2<br>of 2</strong></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    

    
</body>
```

Comment: can you share the html markup as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below snippet, these are the changes

- added pseudo-classes for only-child
- removed top padding
- removed pseudo-classes for the first list element

```css
*.genealogy-tree li:last-child:only-child::after, .genealogy-tree li:last-child:only-child::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.genealogy-tree > ul > li::after, .genealogy-tree > ul > li::before {
  display: none
}

.genealogy-tree li:only-child{ 
/* padding-top: 0; */
}
```

```css
.genealogy-body{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 50px;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.genealogy-tree{
  display: inline-block;
}
.genealogy-tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.genealogy-tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}
.genealogy-tree li::before, .genealogy-tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 50%;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; 
  height: 18px;
}
.genealogy-tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}

*.genealogy-tree li:last-child:only-child::after, .genealogy-tree li:last-child:only-child::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
left: 50%;
width: 0;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.genealogy-tree > ul > li::after, .genealogy-tree > ul > li::before {
  display: none
}

/*This removes space from the top of single children BUT IT CAUSES MISALIGNMENT SO NEED TO EXTEND LINE SOMEHOW*/
.genealogy-tree li:only-child{ 
/*     padding-top: 0; */
}
/*This removes left connector from first child and right connector from last child*/
.genealogy-tree li:first-child::before, .genealogy-tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*This adds back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.genealogy-tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.genealogy-tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*This adds downwards connectors from parents*/
.genealogy-tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}
.genealogy-tree li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Lora", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
        
<div class="body genealogy-body genealogy-scroll">
    <div class="genealogy-tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a>
        <div class="member-view-box">
        <div class="member-image">
        <img src="../images/trees/_tree_blank.jpg" alt="refresh your browser...">
        <div class="member-details">
        <span><strong>Top<br>Line</strong></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>        
            <a>
            <div class="member-view-box">
            <div class="member-image">
            <div class="member-details">
            <span><strong>PARENT<br>WITH<br>ONE CHILD</strong></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a>
                <div class="member-view-box">
                <div class="member-image">
                <div class="member-details">
                <span><strong>ONLY<br>CHILD</strong><br>* line short *</span>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a>
            <div class="member-view-box">
            <div class="member-image">
            <div class="member-details">
            <span><strong>PARENT<br>WITH<br>TWO CHILDS</strong></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a>
                <div class="member-view-box">
                <div class="member-image">
                <div class="member-details">
                <span><strong>Child 1<br>of 2</strong></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a>
                <div class="member-view-box">
                <div class="member-image">
                <div class="member-details">
                <span><strong>Child 2<br>of 2</strong></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    

    
</body>
```